# Function not working the same way when using lapply

Tags: r, function, lapply

First off - I apologise for the badly phrased question, if you have any more appropriate suggestions for it I'm all ears!

I have written a function that adds a new variable into my df based on what the object is called. For example, I have `x_data`, and when I put it into my function, a new variable called `x_or_y` is created, with all entries showing "x". You guessed it - there is also a `y_data`, that when plugged into the function it creates the same variable `x_or_y` and fills it with "y"

I'm having some issues however when I have a list of dfs (`x_data` and `y_data`) and I use `lapply()` to the list - it just returns the same letter for all. See below my example.

#### Example:

```
set.seed(123)
x_data <- data.frame(A = rnorm(20),
                 B = rnorm(20))
y_data <- data.frame(A = rnorm(20),
                 B = rnorm(20))
```

Function for "x or y":

```
add_x_or_y  <- function(z) {
  z$x_or_y <- ifelse(grepl(pattern = "x", 
                                 deparse(substitute(z)), fixed = TRUE), 
                           "x", "y")
  z
}
```

So trying the function out by itself:

```
head(add_x_or_y(x_data),3)

            A          B x_or_y
1 -0.56047565 -1.0678237      x
2 -0.23017749 -0.2179749      x
3  1.5587083 -1.0260044       x

head(add_x_or_y(y_data),3)

           A          B x_or_y
1 -0.6947070  0.3796395      y
2 -0.2079173 -0.5023235      y
3 -1.2653964 -0.3332074      y
```

Okay, so that works - but in real life I have about 20 different dfs that I need to put through the function. That's a lot of wasted space writing it each time, so let's make a list and use `lapply()`.

```
x_y_list <- list(x_data = x_data,
                 y_data = y_data)
x_y_list <- lapply(x_y_list, add_x_or_y)

head(x_y_list$x_data,3)
           A          B x_or_y
1 -0.5604756 -1.0678237      y
2 -0.2301775 -0.2179749      y
3  1.5587083 -1.0260044      y

head(x_y_list$y_data,3)
           A          B x_or_y
1 -0.6947070  0.3796395      y
2 -0.2079173 -0.5023235      y
3 -1.2653964 -0.3332074      y
```

It didn't work! :( The first one should have "x"'s in the `x_or_y` variable. I'm sure it's a really really simple solution here, but I cannot seem to find it - please help Stack Overflow!

Comment: As far as I can tell, you'll have to pass `names(x_y_list)` to a modified function to achieve the same behavior

Comment: Put `print(deparse(substitute(z)))` as the first instruction of the function and see what is happening.

Comment: Names objects != Named elements within a list. And please show the *actual* function (or give background to actual problem) as I highly doubt `deparse(substitute(z))` is even needed.

Comment: @RuiBarradas great suggestion using `print()`, this is helping to see what's going on. The function is returning `"X[[i]]"` `"X[[i]]"` which means it's not taking the name of each element in the list, just the subscript. Confused why it shows a capital "X" though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using lapply, you are just handing over the data frames without their names. Perhaps if you change the approach alittle:

```
set.seed(123)
x_data <- data.frame(A = rnorm(20),
                     B = rnorm(20))
y_data <- data.frame(A = rnorm(20),
                     B = rnorm(20))

add_x_or_y <- function(df, df_name) {
  df$x_or_y <- ifelse(grepl("x", df_name) == TRUE, "x", "y")
  df
}

x_y_list <- list(x_data = x_data,
                 y_data = y_data)

x_y_list <- mapply(add_x_or_y, 
                   x_y_list, 
                   names(x_y_list), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

head(x_y_list$x_data, 3)
head(x_y_list$y_data, 3)
```

Comment: Brilliant! This does the job :) I didn't even think to add another argument, but it makes a lot of sense. I've learnt something today - thank you!